# How could I check the closedness under multiplication of the ring of symmetric functions?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\Lambda$ be the ring of symmetric functions, which is defined as the subspace of the power series ring over $\mathbb{C}$ generated by monomial symmetric functions. Now, the monomial symmetric function corresponding a partition $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_l)$ is defined by the sum taken over all distinct monomials in the $S_{\infty}$-orbit of $$X_{i_1}^{\lambda_1}\cdots X_{i_l}^{\lambda_l}$$

I want to show that $\Lambda$ is closed under multiplication, so it is indeed a ring. But I don't know how to prove this! Could you give me some hint or solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you define things properly, you will see that the statement is obvious.

First of all, let $P_n=F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be the polynomial ring in $n$-variables (here $F$ is an arbitrary field, but could also be taken to be any commutative ring).

There is a surjective homomorphism $P_{n+1}\twoheadrightarrow P_n$ determined by the mapping $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n,x_{n+1})\mapsto f(x_1,\ldots,x_n,0)$ and we define 
$$P_\infty=\lim_{\leftarrow}P_n.$$

Now, for each $n$, the symmetric group $S_n$ acts on $P_n$ by permuting the variables:
$$\sigma.f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=f(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)}).$$
This action is by ring automorphisms and we immediately have that the space $\Lambda_n=P_n^{S_n}$ of $S_n$-invariants is a ring. The surjections $P_{n+1}\twoheadrightarrow P_n$ restrict to surjections $\Lambda_{n+1}\twoheadrightarrow \Lambda_n$, and we may construct the ring
$$\Lambda=\Lambda_\infty=\lim_{\leftarrow}\Lambda_n.$$

It is now just left to observe that $\Lambda=P_\infty^{S_\infty}$ where $\displaystyle S_\infty=\lim_{\rightarrow}S_n$ is the direct limit with respect to the obvious embedding $S_n\to S_{n+1}$ and acts on $P_\infty$ in the obvious way.